# Executable file for automation testing using C#, .net and TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, tfs, automation

We recently developed a small framework using NUnit C# for automation testing. I am actually new to this. Usually I execute the test cases using Test Explorer. But my client wants the package to be checked in to TFS and execute it through TFS with some click buttons. Basically to make it clear they don't want them to see the code just the test cases and pick the cases and run them externally but not through Visual studio.

Can anyone provide me your suggestions on this on how to achieve it?

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? What hasn't worked?

Answer (score -1):

> Executable file for automation testing using C#, .net and TFS

What you are looking for should be how to create a test plan or test case to run the automated tests. But this is a broad question. There is no way to give you an accurate answer. You need to check certain documents and make certain attempts. If you encounter any specific problems, you can ask it.

For the Test Plan, which part of Microsoft Test Manager, which is a tool for creating and running manual tests, and managing test/lab environments.

Then we could the automated tests after we create  the test case:

[image]

You could check this document [Azure Test Plans documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Comment: Thank you for the good input that you gave. I think this might help me to look into the options that I have. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: @Meghasri, You are always welcome. Looking forward to your reply, have a nice day!

Comment: I have tried using command prompt. That is one way to achieve the execution without opening visual studio. It really worked for me and awesome it is. I am looking for another way of approach like to have a 'Run Test' button in TFS server so that when someone executes from the server by clicking one button without having visual studio installed, the test cases should get executed in the server. If you have any idea on this how i can achieve it please do let me know. Thank you